# OSPF Data Center Design

Tags: cisco, ospf, design

I'm thinking about doing a routed access layer datacenter design with OSPF.

1. couple TORs switches from every rack connect to a pair of core switches via l3 links
2. every rack is it's own totally stubby area. About 200 racks, total about 400 switches. TORs are either 4948s or nexus 3k
3. Core Acts as ABRs. Cores are chassis bases high end boxes (nexus 7k, or juniper 9200 etc)

The idea is to just have a default on the TORs and keep the LSA database small, hence unique area per rack. Should i be concerned about ABRs (cores) generating that many type 3 LSA for different areas?

Comment: Thank you for asking; could you rephrase the question without an open-ended poll for "if anyone has done a similar design...".  I suggest adding your own personal fears and concerns for us to respond to; without this, the question is off-topic since it is a [Poll](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255/)

Comment: edited. I'm really just trying to find out info from people who may be running similar designs

Comment: I need to edit the poll out...looks fine otherwise.  FYI polls are welcome in our chat room but you need 20 points

Comment: Why do you feel the need to divide it up into so many areas?  Your design doesn't offer any advantages (that I can think of) over keeping things at L2, using per-rack VLANs, trunking data back to the core, and letting the core handle all routing.

Comment: Also, if you run ESXi and want to be able to vMotion from rack to rack, you'll be out of luck if you don't have the ability to trunk VLANs to different racks.  Even with physical servers/devices, if you ever need to shift something to a different rack, you'll need to update DNS, IP addresses, etc.  From my point of view, you're setting yourself up for a lot of hurt.

Comment: spanning vlan across rack is not a requirement. We're not looking to run spanning tree in this environment hence the routed design. different areas so i don't have 600 switches in same area

Comment: @AveryAbbott If there isn't a distinct reason to use trunks, it's generally better not to.  The **only** reason I use them in my environment is to conserve IP space.  Switching has great advantages inside data centers with sub-second switching and all that jazz, but it isn't tolerant of link failures, doesn't offer any path selection capabilities, and disables redundant links. If I were the OP'er, I would be doing the _exact_ same thing; though, I may setup the areas a little differently.

Comment: Unless I missed something, all data is funneled via TOR switches to the core, so there's no link failure tolerance anyway, nor are there multiple paths to choose from / load balance across, nor are there redundant links.  Where's the benefit to L3 in this case?

At L2, you have options for active-active connections using VSS, Trill, SPBM, etc.  Spanning tree is old-hat.

Comment: _"couple TORs switches from every rack connect to a pair of core switches via l3 links"_. Multiple links to multiple core switches.

Comment: there are multiple links, one to each core and use ECMP for load balancing.

Comment: @iosjunos I personally feel like those are ideal platforms for ABRs, I've just never dealt with or had a need for that many areas before.  However, there are folks on this forum that have more than enough knowledge to intelligently answer this (probably through experience). Perhaps a good network diagram might entice some of them; not a requirement, though.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend moving to an OSPF/iBGP design for something of this scale, with the core switches acting as BGP route reflectors.  BGP has so many more administrative handles for tinkering with routes over OSPF, allowing better scale and filtering.

If you scale to the point that you have more networks than your ToR switches can program into CAM (unlikely if each is a different stub), you run into issues.  Each additional zone is more CPU load on your ABRs (core switches) as well.

Have one OSPF area 0, with all loopbacks and router-to-router links in it.  Then setup iBGP sessions between your cores and ToR, advertising default-only to ToR, and redistribute connected/static routes on ToR into BGP.

Comment: Great insight; with a network of this size, you do need **some** level of path control which you just won't get with OSPF.

Comment: yes eBGP CLOS design is also in consideration.
http://forums.juniper.net/t5/Data-Center-Technologists/BGP-in-the-Data-Center-Why-you-need-to-deploy-it-now/ba-p/227547
 thx